# Image processing with Play Framework

Tags: java, image, playframework

I have the following code to get a profile picture from facebook, resize it if necessary, and crop it to have a nice square picture:

```
            url = new URL(profilePictureUrl);
            InputStream stream = url.openStream();

            // Create the file from the URL
            File temp = File.createTempFile(Codec.UUID(), "temp");
            OutputStream out = null;
            try {
                out = new FileOutputStream(temp);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                Logger.error("SF-ERROR : Error creating temp file", e1);
            }

            int read = 0;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

            while ((read = stream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                out.write(bytes, 0, read);
            }

            stream.close();
            out.close();

            String uuid = Codec.UUID();
            File resizedFile = File.createTempFile("resized-" + uuid, ".image");
            File croppedFile = File.createTempFile("cropped-" + uuid, ".image");

            // Check that this is in fact, an image
            if (temp != null && ImageIO.read(temp) != null) {

                int height = ImageIO.read(temp).getHeight();
                int width = ImageIO.read(temp).getWidth();

                double newWidth = (height * 180) / (width);

                boolean high = false;
                boolean wide = false;

                if (newWidth > 220) {
                    high = true;
                }
                if (newWidth < 140) {
                    wide = true;
                }

                if (height > width) {
                    // Resize the image to a width of 180 pixels.
                    Images.resize(temp, resizedFile, 180, -1);
                } else {
                    // Resize the image to a height of 180 pixels.
                    Images.resize(temp, resizedFile, -1, 180);
                }

                // Crop the remaining width or height to 180 pixels. This way we get a nice square picture.
                if (high) {
                    Images.crop(resizedFile, croppedFile, 0, 20, 180, 200);
                } else if (wide) {
                    Images.crop(resizedFile, croppedFile, 20, 0, 200, 180);
                } else {
                    Images.crop(resizedFile, croppedFile, 0, 0, 180, 180);
                }
```

The wide and high booleans are there so that the crop is taken roughly in the middle..

This works, but is taking an awfull lot of time.

Anyone can see if this can be done quicker, or if I am doing something wrong?

Comment: PS: I cannot use image4j as I can't install it on my server, so stuck with the Play methods for image processing.

Comment: Why not use Java2D to resize?

Comment: I think you want to at least make the http get call asynchronous and possibly also the resizing part.